# Can I only insert into 1 table during a session in php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
if (isset($_POST["AddErrorCode"]))
{
    $AddErrorCodeDB = $_POST["AddErrorCode"];
    $AddErrorDescriptionDB = $_POST["AddErrorDescription"];
    $AddQuantityDB = $_POST["AddQuantity"];
    $AddStartDateDB = $_POST["AddStartDate"];
    $AddCompletionDateDB = $_POST["AddCompletionDate"];
    $AddReviewTypeDB = $_POST["AddReviewType"];
    session_start();
    $WO_ID = $_SESSION['SELECTED_WO_ID'];
    if ($AddReviewTypeDB === 'PR')
    {
        $AddReviewerType = 'Peer Review';
        $insert = "INSERT INTO `wo_errorinfo` (
                        `Error_Code` ,
                        `Error_Description` ,
                        `Error_Quantity` ,
                        `Review_Type` ,
                        `WO_NO`) VALUES (
                        '$AddErrorCodeDB' ,
                        '$AddErrorDescriptionDB' , 
                        '$AddQuantityDB' ,
                        '$AddReviewerType' ,
                        '$WO_ID')";

        if ($AddCompletionDateDB === '')
        {
            //echo 'ritwik';
            $status = 'Peer RWK';
            $update = "UPDATE `associated_wos` SET `WO Status` = '$status' WHERE `ID` = '$WO_ID'";
        }
        else
        {
            //echo 'ritwik1';
            $status = 'Peer Review Complete';
            $update = "UPDATE `associated_wos` SET `WO Status` = '$status' WHERE `ID` = '$WO_ID'";
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `wo_reviewerqa` WHERE `WO_ID` = '$WO_ID' AND `reviewType` = '$AddReviewerType'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        //echo $num_rows;
        if ($num_rows === 0)
        {
            //echo 'ritwik';
            $insertreview = "INSERT INTO `wo_reviewerqa` (
                                `reviewType`,
                                `reviewStartDate`,
                                `reviewCompleteDate`,
                                `WO_ID`) VALUES (
                                '$AddReviewerType',
                                '$AddStartDateDB',
                                '$AddCompletionDateDB' ,
                                '$WO_ID')";
            //echo $insertreview;
        }
else
        {
            if ($AddStartDateDB !== '')
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Review Already Started, Start Date cant be changed');</script>";
            }
        }
        if($conn->query($insertreview) === True)
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Start date updated successfully');</script>";
        }
        if ($conn->query($insert) === True)
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error Code Submitted successfully');</script>";
        }
    }
```

All my condition are getting satisfied. I am even getting all the correct values in the echo but only the first insert query i.e. `insert into 'wo_errorinfo'` is working and all else are having no effect on the table. Can we not insert into multiple tables during a session. Is it due to `session_start()`? I have been trying to figure this out for more 1 day now but can't figure it.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the session, no. Where are you actually executing your insert and update queries? I can see you create the SQL strings but not actually run them.

Comment: By the way, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL like this.

Comment: @ADyson You mean this $conn->query($insert)

Comment: yes, where do you run this? And where do you run all the others (the ones you say don't work)? Do you ever check that they succeed (by checking the value returned by the query() method)?

Comment: Below this code.

Comment: please actually edit your code to show us, since it's relevant to the question. We can't really start to talk about why queries fail when we can't see how they get executed or how you check for errors.

Comment: So silly of me. I am really sorry. Just figured I had not written all the run statements of the query. Only first and last one so that's why they are not working. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it takes someone else to point out something so obvious. We are only human after all. You can delete the question then, if it's not useful.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks.  Can't delete it due to some policy of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute your statements, currently only `$sql` is executed.

You should also avoid building queries by concatenating strings as this will leave you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks where your users can modify your queries by passing special characters in the input. You should use [mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), e.g:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();
}
```